# Receive photo from previous activity to the current one

Tags: android

This is my code to launch the camera and take a photo and send as Intent to another activity:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_image, container, false);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addImage);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Launching Camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("putSomething", true);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                //ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


                Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.toString(),options);

                Intent imagepass = new Intent(getActivity(),StoreImage.class);
                imagepass.putExtra("imagepass", receipt );
                startActivity(imagepass);
            }
    }
```

Now in the receiving activity how do i show the photo captured by the camera, what should i add to the xml file to display the image in a GridView

here's my code:

```
public class StoreImage extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_image);
    //creating view ids


    Bitmap receiptimage = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("imagepass");
    receipt.setImageBitmap(receiptimage);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What is the receipt variable in your onCreate for StoreImage activity, it should refer to an ImageView in the xml like this.

```
Bitmap receiptimage = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("imagepass");
ImageView receipt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.receiptImageView);
receipt.setImageBitmap(receiptimage);
```