# Send photo from one activity to another captured through custom camera

Tags: android

I have the following code, but i don't know whether it is correct or not, in the app it crashes and shows NullPointer Exception in Logcat at :        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

Here's the code which opens the camera intent:

```
public class AddImage extends Fragment {

Button button;
View view;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA = 100;
private Uri fileUri;
String image_path = "";
Button button1;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_image, container, false);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addImage);
    button1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.goImage);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent iSecond=new Intent(getActivity(),ShowImage.class);
            iSecond.putExtra("image_path",image_path);
            startActivity(iSecond);
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Launching Camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 0);


        }
    });
    return view;
}






@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {


            image_path = fileUri.getPath();



        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}







public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

The receiving Activity:

```
public class ShowImage extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImage);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {

        String image_path = extras.getString("image_path");
    }
    File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/1426484497.png");

    if (imgFile.exists()) {

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                .getAbsolutePath());

        iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
}
```

}

NullPointer Exception at  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Can anyone help me out!

P.S also how to show the captured images in GridView in the receiving activity!

Comment: Why ask same question over and over
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508033/receive-photo-from-previous-activity-to-the-current-one/32516867?noredirect=1#comment52892556_32516867

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

NullPointer Exception is occurring because `intent` is `null`.

initialize intent as:

```
intent= getIntent();
```

before calling `getExtras` .

Comment: Yes, i have done that but there is no image in the new activity, can you please tell where i have gone wrong in the camera intent class

Comment: @bappibazzi: what value u are getting in `image_path` String ?

Comment: @bappibazzi: also change `Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);` to `fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);`

Comment: mParcellData.dataSize = 44

Comment: @bappibazzi: also change Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image); to fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

Comment: But why is the image not being received?

Comment: @bappibazzi: what data u are getting in `String image_path = extras.getString("image_path");` ?

Comment: mParcellData.dataSize = 44

Comment: @bappibazzi: what is `mParcellData.dataSize = 44` ?

Comment: I went in the debug mode and got that value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89355/discussion-between-bappi-bazzi-and--k).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you declared **External storage read write permission** in manifest!

and change,

Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

to,

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: I got that but the image captured is not appearing in the second activity, can you look at the camera intent code and please tell where i've gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

change `startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 0);` to `startActivityForResult(imageIntent,REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA);`

Comment: does it works @bappi bazzi ?? . I seen startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0) in your code posted

Comment: can you help me please!

Comment: see if you have not changed it like above , image path will be  "" , and you can't get any thing. also to retrieve  use getIntent().getStringExtra(image_path)

Comment: is there any thing else i can do!